# Does deleting a AWs Rekognition Collection also faces in it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

Does deleting a AWs Rekognition Collection also deletes all the faces registered into it? Or do we need to delete all faces separately? I am checking the documentation but unable to find concrete information on this.

Pls advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [DeleteCollection - Amazon Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteCollection.html):

> Deletes the specified collection. Note that this operation removes all faces in the collection.

While the word 'remove' doesn't explicitly say 'delete', the fact is that Faces only exist within Collections. So, removing a Face from a Collection effectively deletes the Face.